# Searching for a string between two characters

Tags: bash, awk

I need to find two numbers from lines which look like this

```
>Chr14:453901-458800
```

I have a large quantity of those lines mixed with lines that doesn't contain ":" so we can search for colon to find the line with numbers. Every line have different numbers.

I need to find both numbers after `":"` which are separated by `"-"` then substract the first number from the second one and print result on the screen for each line

I'd like this to be done using awk

I managed to do something like this:

```
awk -e '$1 ~ /\:/ {print $0}' file.txt
```

but it's nowhere near the end result

For this example i showed above my result would be:

```
4899
```

Because it is the result of `458800 - 453901 = 4899`

I can't figure it out on my own and would appreciate some help

Comment: Just for fun: `grep -o ':.*' file | tr :- -+ | bc` (with GNU grep)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU `awk`. Separate the row into multiple columns using the `:` and `-` separators. In each row containing `:`, subtract the contents of column 2 from the contents of column 3 and print result.

```
awk -F '[:-]' '/:/{print $3-$2}' file
```

Output:

```
4899
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`

```
$ awk -F: '/:/ {split($2,a,"-"); print a[2] - a[1]}' input_file
4899
```